# Merging Many Webms With FFMPEG

Tags: merge, ffmpeg, webm

We've been trying to merge multiple `webms` together so that they play in series in a new `webm` using `FFMPEG`. These `webms` are from multiple sources (webcams), so the resolution will vary.

We're using these options, it works perfectly for 3 files. But, we need to be able to do it for n number video files.

```
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=640:-1[v1]; [0:v][0:a][v1][1:a][2:v]
[2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"
```

Comment: Why don't you iterate over all files in folder using bash or something and change resolution to the needed one, and then just concatenate them all

Comment: Is it Windows, Linux, OSX, another?